# Does a frequency list categorized by parts of speech exist already?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

For a project that I am creating, I am looking for a frequency list of German words divided by parts of speech.  Ideally, it would be divided into several lists of lemmas, each with their own part of speech.  Unfortunately, I don't think I can use a part of speech tagger on a normal frequency list, POS taggers use context to figure it out.  Is the only way to do this to run a POS tagger on a large corpus, then divide each POS by frequency?

Comment: I don't know if a search for resources or tools is on-topic here. Adding an example to your question how you imagine this list might help to understand what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

There are written books about that.<sup>([1](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_der_h%C3%A4ufigsten_W%C3%B6rter_der_deutschen_Sprache))</sup> Try to find an online representation of it, or favourably a database you can access. Follow the link.